# How do I put a Jmol applet into a webpage?

Tags: java, javascript, applet, html

I have downloaded Jmol on to my computer.
I then click "File, then "Export to Webpage"
I then clicked the ScriptButton Jmol tab

I do not understand what to put into "Relative Server path to jar files" input
as well as the "Relative Local Path to jar files "input.

Can anyone explain to me what these mean, or have an easier way to get my jmol applet onto a webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Put the HTML in the same directory as the Jar(s) for local and server, and the answer for both is the same - `"."`.  The `.` means 'current directory'.